# How can I read apple iOS documentation correctly?

Tags: ios, swift, documentation

I was following a tutorial I found on the web, there was line of code like this:

```
var myImage = UIImage(named: "icon")
```

I understand what this line does, but I don't want to memorize it of course, I want to understand how the author came up with this code, so I search the documentation for UIImage class reference, there is nothing under the initializers section that identify this code, so why? Where can I find more about this code?

I read a lot of tutorials I found on the web, watched a lot of video tutorials, and read a lot of books, ALL of them with no exceptions they show you the code, they fully explain it, BUT they don't tell you how they came up with it, how did they find the right method for the right job?

Should I spend my time reading Apple documentation instead of all these tutorials? Is there something I'm doing wrong? Am I missing something? I don't want to memorize all the stuff I read, that's not why I wanted to learn developing apps, I want to understand where to look to find the right code, I want to learn to think like a developer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are 3 useful sources of written information:

1. Example code/Tutorials:
   The official documentation is great once you have some experience coding in Xcode/iOS, but it is a hard place to start.  Nothing beats looking at good sample code.
   Example code (from Apple, from Stack Overflow, from Ray Wenderlich, from anywhere you can find it) is a great way to learn.  Even people writing the tutorials you are reading started with other people's sample code.  The first people learning iOS started with sample code from Apple.
2. The official documentation:
   To get the the official documentation <kbd>option</kbd>click on `UIImage` in your code or in the Playground.  In the pop up, select *UIImage Class Reference*.  The initializer you are looking for is there:

   > `+ imageNamed:`
   >  Returns the image object associated with the specified filename.
   >
   > **Declaration**
   >  SWIFT
   >  `init?(named name: String) -> UIImage`
   >  OBJECTIVE-C
   >   `+ (UIImage *)imageNamed:(NSString *)name`
   >  **Parameters**
   >  *name*   The name of the file. If this is the first time the image is being loaded, the
   >   method looks for an image with the specified name in the application’s
   >   main bundle.
   >  **Return Value** The image object for the specified file, or
   >   nil if the method could not find the specified image.

   In Swift, of course, you don't call initializers directly by calling `init`.  Instead, you use the class name, `UIImage` in this case.  `name` is the internal name of the parameter, and the `?` tells you this is a failable initializer that might return `nil`, so in fact this initializer returns a `UIImage?`.  So you should look at `init?(named name: String) -> UIImage` and think `UIImage(named: String) -> UIImage?`.
3. The header files:
     Type `UIImage` into your code or a Playground and <kbd>Command</kbd>-click on it.  That will bring up the header file information for `UIImage`.  The very first initializer listed is:

   ```
   init?(named name: String) -> UIImage // load from main bundle
   ```

You can learn a lot from reading the headers.  I recommend checking them frequently.

Answer (score 6):

The tricky bit is the way Swift deals with initializers. I suggest "buying" the free "The Swift Programming Language" iBook and reading the chapter on initializers.

The word "init" appears in the declaration of an initializer, but you don't use the word init when calling it.

The declaration is

```
init?(named name: String) -> UIImage
```

The question mark tells you that it is a "failable" initializer.

Instead of calling it with the word init, you put the class name as if it's the method name, and the parameters after:

```
UIImage(named: "name")
```

It gets more complex for init methods like `initWithFrame:`. In that case it parses the "with" away, and creates a parameter "frame".

I'm not going to cover everything here. (I'm still learning the nuances myself.) Like I said, read the chapter on initializers in the Swift iBook.

Answer (score 1):

1) It is in "Cached Image Loading Routines" section. Maybe you need to switch to Swift code in documentation?

2) Tutorials and code examples are good to learn language, platform and good practices. You can backup it with references lecture.

Comment: How do you switch to Swift code in the documentation?

Comment: On the top right corner of each class documentation site you have "Language: Objective-C Swift Both". Just choose what you need.

Comment: "On the top right corner of each class documentation site?" You mean on the help window in Xcode? Where, exactly, and what is it near? I don't see it.

Comment: I believe @Maciej means in the online documentation (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/) There's are the buttons, as they described, in the top-right corner(-ish). They're quite small and easy to miss though.

Comment: @DuncanC Oh, right. I didn't mention that's online Apple documentation.